# Can my Excel Function regarding year and month left to pay a debt at a specified rate be streamlined at all?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, performance

I wanted to make a sentence in Excel that would read "You will be free of debt in X years and X months, at $X per month." and stick it at the bottom of my budget so as to motivate myself. I used the values for:Total Debts (B27), and Amount Paid per Month (C23). Using only those reference values, and without using hidden cells, I put together the following:

> ="You will be free of debt in "&IF(ROUND(SUM(B27/C23),0)<12, 0, ROUND(SUM(B27/C23)/12,0))&" years and "&(IF(IF(MOD(ROUND(SUM(B27/C23),0),12)=0,0,(SUM(ROUND(SUM(B27/C23),0),-(12*ROUND(SUM(ROUND(SUM(B27/C23),0)/12),0)))))>0,IF(MOD(ROUND(SUM(B27/C23),0),12)=0,0,(SUM(ROUND(SUM(B27/C23),0),-(12*ROUND(SUM(ROUND(SUM(B27/C23),0)/12),0))))),(SUM(IF(MOD(ROUND(SUM(B27/C23),0),12)=0,0,(SUM(ROUND(SUM(B27/C23),0),-(12*ROUND(SUM(ROUND(SUM(B27/C23),0)/12),0)))))+12))))&" months at "&DOLLAR(C23)&" per month."

It works, but it isn't pretty, and I want it to be prettier. Are there any functions that I could be using that I don't know about, or is this as pretty as it gets without using hidden cells?

Comment: Use VBA? Unless you need the function to be easily accessible for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

If A1 = total debt and A2 = monthly payments then...

Years remaining = FLOOR(A1/(A2*12),1)

and ...

Months remaining = CEILING((A1-A2*12*(FLOOR(A1/(A2*12),1)))/A2,1)

In your sheet this should work...

="You will be free of debt in "&FLOOR(B27/(C23*12),1)&" years and "&CEILING((B27-C23*12*(FLOOR(B27/(C23*12),1)))/C23,1)&" months, at $"&C23&" per month."